# Need query without custom variable

Tags: mysql

I have table (my_table) like below

```
Sku |   Date        |   Quantity
a   |   2014-01-21  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-20  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-19  |   3 
a   |   2014-01-18  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-17  |   5 
a   |   2014-01-16  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-15  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-14  |   2 
a   |   2014-01-13  |   1 
a   |   2014-01-12  |   1
```

### Output

If sum of quantity is >= 10 then need to get the corresponding date. I mean need to execute each row and simultaneously sum the quantity and when quantity reach greater then or equal to 10 the get then corresponding date from that row.

From the above table my output date should be "2014-01-17".

I have already written script with custom variable (given below).Its working fine.

```
SET @qnty := NULL;
SELECT @d AS Date FROM (
    SELECT Quantity,
        @qnty := IF(@qnty IS NULL, Quantity, @qnty+Quantity),
        @d := IF(@qnty >= 10, Date, @d) 
        FROM `my_table` 
        WHERE Quantity > 0
            AND `Sku` = 'a'
        ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
) a
LIMIT 1
```

However I need a query without custom variables since I need to use this query as sub-query of another VIEW.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Your query does not return what you describle. This makes your question hard to understand. Are you really expecting one single result?

Comment: I have updated my query to return single result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
select
  my_table.sku,
  my_table.dt
from my_table 
where
  (select sum(my_table2.Quantity) from my_table as my_table2
   where my_table2.sku = my_table.sku and
         my_table2.dt >= my_table.dt) >= 10
  and
  coalesce((select sum(my_table2.Quantity) from my_table as my_table2
            where my_table2.sku = my_table.sku and 
                  my_table2.dt > my_table.dt), 0) < 10
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00fb3/6).

**Edit** : Improved the solution to manage multiple SKU.

Comment: Thanks for your query. I have verified your query in the fiddle and its showing wrong date for SKU 'B'. My expected result for SKU 'B' is January 10 but its showing Jan 15.

Comment: Do you have to get the row when sum is 10 starting from a given date ascending or descending?  (It is ascending right now.)

Comment: I need to get the date in Descending order. Thanks

Comment: When I am executing same in my original table which has more than 50k rows, it takes long time. Please suggest me to resolve the performance issue

Comment: I edited my answer (descending order).  For your performance issue it is a whole new problem (never mentionned 50k rows before!).

Comment: Thank you so much for your query. Its working as expected. However it would be helpful if you provide any suggestion to resolve the performance issue. Thanks